# What exactly is the process to calculate $10^{2.2}$ without using a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Like for example: if the question is $10^3$, then we can write it as $10*10*10$ and solve, so if the question is in decimals how exactly will it be done?

Comment: In the past (*and still rarely today*) one could and would use things such as [logarithm tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table#Tables_of_logarithms) or [slide rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule).  One would using such a table be able to find an approximation of the value of $\ln 10^{2.2}=2.2\ln 10$ and then be able to find a good approximation of the value of $e^{(2.2\ln 10)}=10^{2.2}$.  Such tables would even be included in older textbooks in either the first few pages or the last few pages for quick reference.

Comment: @amWhy $12/5 = 2.4$, while $2.2 = 11/5$

Comment: oops, thanks, @rubik

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rough approximation.

$2^{10} = 1024 \approx 10^3\\
10^{0.3} \approx 2\\
10^{1.2} = (10^{0.3})^4 \approx 2^4\\
10^{2.2} = 10\cdot 10^{1.2} \approx 10\cdot 2^4 = 160$

vs. 158.5 from my computer.

Answer (score 2):

$$10^{2.2}=100\exp (0.2\ln 10)\approx 100\exp 0.46=100\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{0.46^n}{n!}\approx100\sum_{n= 0}^3\frac{0.46^n}{n!}\approx 158.$$

Answer (score 0):

Derived from *Newton's method*:

As you only have to compute $\sqrt[5]{10}$, here an algorithm: the sequence defined recursively by $x_0>0$, say $x=2$, and
$$x_{n+1}=\frac 45 \,x_n+\frac{a}{5\mkern 1mux_n^4},$$
converges to  $\sqrt[5]{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

For a very small improvement over the accuracy of Doug M's answer, at the expense of a bit of arithmetic, we have

$$\begin{align}
10^{2.2}&=100\cdot10^{1/5}\\
&=50\cdot320^{1/5}\quad(\text{since }2^5=32)\\
&=50(243+77)^{1/5}\\
&=50\cdot3\left(1+{77\over243} \right)^{1/5}\quad(\text{since }3^5=243)\\
&\approx150\left(1+{1\over5}\cdot{77\over243} \right)\\
&=150+{770\over81}\\
&=159+{41\over81}\\
&\approx159.5
\end{align}$$

The error comes mainly from truncating the Taylor series for $(1+x)^{1/5}$ at $1+{1\over5}x$ with $x=77/243\approx0.317$, which isn't small enough for the linear approximation to be all that accurate. (The linear approximation does give an upper bound, though, since the Taylor series alternates thereafter, i.e., $(1+x)^{1/5}=1+{1\over5}x-{4\over25}x^2+{36\over125}x^3-\cdots$.)

Added later: A better approximation can be obtained from observing that

$$10\cdot5^5=31250=32768-1518=2^{15}-1518$$

which gives

$$\begin{align}
10^{2.2}&=100\cdot10^{1/5}\\
&=20\cdot31250^{1/5}\\
&=20\cdot8\left(1-{1518\over2^{15}}\right)^{1/5}\\
&\approx5\cdot2^5\left(1-{1\over5}\cdot{759\over2^{14}}\right)\\
&=160-{759\over512}\\
&=159-{247\over512}\\
&\approx158.5
\end{align}$$

In this case we have $(1-x)^{1/5}\approx1-{1\over5}x-{4\over25}x^2-\cdots$ with $x=1518/32768\approx0.046$, which gives much quicker convergence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this equation to split the powers and compute seperatly

$$a^n=a^{\lfloor n \rfloor} \times a^{n - \lfloor n \rfloor}$$

This splits the power into a integer part multiplied by a decimal part.
This can then be simplified to

$$a^n = a^{\lfloor n \rfloor} \times \sqrt[\frac 1 {n - \lfloor n \rfloor}]a$$

This looks complicated, but when you sub in it becomes clearer.

$$10^{2.2}=10^2 \times 10^{0.2}$$
$$10^{2.2}=100 \times \sqrt[\frac 1 {0.2}]{10}$$
$$10^{2.2}=100\sqrt[5]{10}$$

Comment: I think the OP wants a decimal approximation. You've just rewritten the expression (correctly) with different notation.